# Creating a Keyboard Shortcut in Emacs for a Command in Auctex

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I have created a custom command in the command list in Auctex. I want to be able to set it to a key binding like the View command which is `C-c C-v`. I know how to set global key bindings in the `.emacs`. I'm not sure how to do it for a custom command.

Here is the line I add into `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'TeX-command-list'("Doall" "%`%l%(mode)%' %t; bibtex %s && %`%l%(mode)%' %t && %`%l%(mode)%' %t && %V" TeX-run-TeX t t :help "Run LaTeX BibTeX LaTeX LaTeX View"))
```

Any help on what to put after it to bind this to a key would be great.

Comment: Would `C-c C-c d RET` cut it for you? Once you add the custom command to your `.emacs` file, that would be all you need to do to run it.

Comment: @Ricardo - I guess that will cut it. Sometimes it asked me if 'Doall' for process 'master' do you want to kill it?? No why it would be doing this? I think it never stops running the view command. I am not sure why. Never had an issue when I ran the commands and view separately.

Comment: @Ricardo - I got it sorted. Need to make it a && instead of a ; for some reason. I think that command wasn't getting killed. Not sure but thanks for the help. I would like if possible to use Rudiger solution. It didn't seem to work but not sure why.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use TeX-command to call the command. It should look something like:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (local-set-key "\C-c\C-v"
                (lambda ()
                   (interactive)
                   (TeX-save-document (TeX-master-file))
                   (TeX-command "Doall" 'TeX-master-file' -1)))))
```

(untested)

Comment: I couldn't get this working correctly. I understand the code but whenever I set it the key binding never worked. Thanks for the help.That's a good solution maybe eventually I'll get it going correctly.