# Add key binding to emacs in AucTeX does not fully work

Tags: emacs, auctex

Based on the discussion in these questions ([1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20843/useful-shortcuts-or-key-bindings-or-predefined-commands-for-emacsauctex), [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25397/creating-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-emacs-for-a-command-in-auctex), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14629198/redefine-auctex-font-and-compile-keybindings)), I created the following key bindings for [AucTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) in [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

```
(defun AucTeX-LaTeX-beginendgroup ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup
")
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-}") "\\endgroup
"))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'AucTeX-LaTeX-beginendgroup)
```

I wanted to create key binding in AucTeX  to input text `\begingroup RET` when `Ctrl-{` is pressed, and input `\endgroup RET` when `Ctrl-}` is pressed.

Emacs loads the style mode hooks successfully without any complaints.

While the first one (`Ctrl-{`), works fine (also `C-h k C-{` reports correctly), the second one (`Ctrl-}`) does not work. Moreover, `C-h k C-}` remains silent without an answer.

I am really clueless about what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't the last argument be a _function_?  In this case one defined to `(insert` the given string.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Then why does the first binding work?

Comment: As commented by Malabarba on the question on mx.sx, sending a string this way outputs the string *as a keyboard macro*. This means inserting the string, if it doesn't contain a character whose key is bound to something different from `self-insert-command`. http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3530/184

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your init file:

```
(eval-after-load "latex"
  '(progn
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-{") "\\begingroup\n")
     (define-key LaTeX-mode-map (kbd "C-}") "\\endgroup\n")))
```

Comment: Your proposed solution produces the same result as mine. The first one works, the second one does not. Even in an uninitialized state emacs remains silent when `Ctrl-}` is pressed. Any idea why this happens? I am using Ubuntu by the way.

Comment: I don't have any idea since it works on my system.  Try commenting in your init file everything except for the above code, perhaps there is something clashing with it.

Comment: I completely emptied my init file. Even then `Ctrl-}` is unresponsive.

Comment: Then I don't think it's an Emacs issue, it seems your system hijacks that key binding .

Comment: @Masroor in ubuntu start off in keyboard settings, I could recreate your problem by assigning say `Ctrl-}` to universal access, for example, and it would remain silent, once in emacs